# Dica pra montar menu

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Bom dia amigos,

Sou novo por aqui e gostaria de contar com a ajuda de vocês, pois preciso montar um menu dropdown, com um dos sub-menus com outro nível. No entanto, pra seguir um layout, tais sub-menus precisam estar na mesma linha e precisa ser um estilo de megamenu. Pesquisei várias opções mais não consegui encontrar algo que me ajudaria. 
Pra exemplificar o que preciso montar vou anexar uma imagem, pra retratar o meu problema

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já fez o [tour], então já deve ter lido quais são as perguntas bem recebidas aqui e você já deve saber que esta não é uma. Ela está insuficientemente clara, não quanto ao objetivo, mas quanto em que você precisa ajuda, e é baseada em opiniões, de certa forma. Como você disse que fez uma pesquisa prévia, já deve ter tentado fazer algo. O melhor será [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código que você fez, descrevendo o saiu inesperado. Só assim teremos um parâmetro concreto para te ajudar.

Comment: Coloque seu `html´ e `css`...

Answer (score -2):

```js
/*global $ */
$(document).ready(function() {

  "use strict";

  $('.menu > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
  //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI

  $('.menu > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
  //Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

  $(".menu > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">Navigation</a>");

  //Adds menu-mobile class (for mobile toggle menu) before the normal menu
  //Mobile menu is hidden if width is more then 959px, but normal menu is displayed
  //Normal menu is hidden if width is below 959px, and jquery adds mobile menu
  //Done this way so it can be used with wordpress without any trouble

  $(".menu > ul > li").hover(function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() > 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

  $(".menu > ul > li").click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 943) {
      $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
    }
  });
  //If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click (thanks Aman Jain from stackoverflow)

  $(".menu-mobile").click(function(e) {
    $(".menu > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  //when clicked on mobile-menu, normal menu is shown as a list, classic rwd menu story (thanks mwl from stackoverflow)

});
```

```css
/* 
- Name: megamenu.js - style.css
- Version: 1.0
- Latest update: 29.01.2016.
- Author: Mario Loncarek
- Author web site: http://marioloncarek.com
*/
/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Body - not related to megamenu
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  color: #333;
}
.description {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
megamenu.js STYLE STARTS HERE
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Screen style's
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.menu-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #e9e9e9;
}
.menu-mobile {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
.menu-mobile:after {
  content: "\f394";
  font-family: "Ionicons";
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-25%);
}
.menu-dropdown-icon:before {
  content: "\f489";
  font-family: "Ionicons";
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}
.menu > ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* IF .menu position=relative -> ul = container width, ELSE ul = 100% width */

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu > ul:before,
.menu > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.menu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5em 3em;
  display: block;
}
.menu > ul > li:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu > ul > li > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  background: none;
  float: left;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul > li a {
  color: #777;
  padding: .2em 0;
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: .8em;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
  border: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub {
  width: 300px;
  left: auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li {
  width: 100%;
}
.menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li a {
  border: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Mobile style's
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .menu-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-dropdown-icon:before {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu > ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu > ul > li a {
    padding: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul.normal-sub {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  .menu .show-on-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">School</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Lidership</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Study</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masters</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Research</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Undergraduate research</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masters research</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Funding</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Something</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub something</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://marioloncarek.com">Contact</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">School</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Lidership</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Study</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masters</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Study</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Undergraduate</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Masters</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Empty sub</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Segue o [link](https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/MKXweV)